# Capturing input from a (proprietary, composite) USB HID

Tags: usb, remapping, hid

I bought a "Genius Wizard Stick" game controller for PC. It's kind of like a Wii remote, but it's 2.4ghz RF (via its own USB receiver). The plan was to use it for desktop and media control, but it only works when the horrible bundled software ("AIWI", a Steam-like client) is running. I don't want to run AIWI.

The interesting thing, and what brings me here, is that it shows up in Win7's Devices & Printers as a composite HID. But it doesn't show up in the Windows gamepad calibration dialogue (via Control Panel), nor does it seem visible to any Windows application - except AIWI.

I thought perhaps it just needs a standalone driver. But because Windows sees it as a HID, it greys out the 'Update Driver' function... so even if such a driver existed, I don't know if it would be the solution. It seems like this device is locked to all but the AIWI software.

The question: Is there a way to capture and map the events from this device? Or is there otherwise a way to 'free' it from being locked to one piece of software?

Comment: The version of AIWI that came with my video card lets you use a phone as a controller over bluetooth. There's a good chance your device is communicating over bluetooth. Getting it to work driverfree is another thing tho

Comment: AIWI uses BT for mobile devices, but the Wizard Stick is RF.